# How to validate multi-dimentional NSArray structure?

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, multidimensional-array, nsarray

Let's say we have `NSArray` of `NSArray`s of `NSNumber`s like this:

```
NSArray *transform = @[
                       @[@1, @0, @1],
                       @[@0.01f, @1, @0],
                       @[@1, @0, @1.1f]
                       ];
```

and we want to validate its structure against the rule **"3x3 `NSArray` of `NSNumber`"**.
The solution I've developed goes like this:

```
BOOL __block validTransform = YES;
if (transform && [transform count] == 3) {
    [transform enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"object: %lu of aClass: %@", idx, [obj class]);
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [obj count] == 3) {
            [obj enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                NSLog(@"- object: %lu of aClass: %@", idx, [obj class]);
                if (![obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
                    validTransform = NO;
                    *stop = YES;
                }
            }];
        } else {
            validTransform = NO;
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
} else validTransform = NO;

NSAssert(validTransform == YES, @"Transform must be 3x3 NSArray of NSNumber");
if (!validTransform) return ...;
```

... and my question is: **Is there any simpler way than this?**

I could change matrix to vector to reduce one dimension but I'd rather something like comparing structures (not values) of input matrix and some reference matrix with same data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is a transformation matrix?

NSArrays and NSNumbers are a bad choice for that. Much better to use a fixed-sized C array or struct. (a matrix)

NSNumbers are immutable, so you have to create a new one any time a value changes.

Traversing the outer array to get to the inner array and then fetching an object from the inner arrays requires method calls, which are slow. Converting an NSNumber to a numeric scalar is also a method call.

Typically transformation matrixes are applied to thousands or even millions of points, so the overhead of using NSArrays adds up. Take a look at the definition of CATransform3D (which is a 4x4 matrix, but it still gives you the idea...)

```
struct CATransform3D
{
  CGFloat m11, m12, m13, m14;
  CGFloat m21, m22, m23, m24;
  CGFloat m31, m32, m33, m34;
  CGFloat m41, m42, m43, m44;
};
```

It's actually a flat 1-dimensional series of floats, which is simpler and  more efficient to deal with.

Comment: Thx for your insight. Ended up with structs.

Answer (score 1):

What you have works so you shouldn't really worry about it. The problem is small enough that you should have no performance issues. You can improve efficiency a little, perhaps, by breaking from the outer loop if the inner loop fails, though only testing would show if this really helped much.

If you're worried about the complexity of the code then add a small comment.

You could split the code into methods to do each level, but really what you have is probably the solution to your problem as it isn't a standard validation, it's a custom structure.

The main alternative would be a different data structure than an array of arrays (like a struct of floats).

Comment: Thx for pointing inner loop break. I ended up with struct, which in fact as you said, doesn't have to be validated at all in this case.